# Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable and only reboot helps

Tags: android, sip

I am developing a simple application that allows user to initiate call using sip protocol.
The problem is inability to create SipSession in some cases (e.g. deleting application with active sip-session, and installing it again).

In this case, I am getting error:

```
android.net.sip.SipException: Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable?
```

And it works only after physical device reboot.

My Sip class:

```
public class SipDataManager {

private Context context;
private SipManager sipManager;
private SipProfile sipProfile;
private SipSession sipSession;
private UserProfile userProfile;

public SipDataManager(Context context, UserProfile userProfile) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userProfile = userProfile;
}

public void initialize() throws SipException {
    Log.d("mylog", "initialize manager");
    if (sipManager == null) {
        Log.d("mylog", "sip manager is not null");
        sipManager = SipManager.newInstance(context);
    }
    initializeProfile();
}

private void initializeProfile() throws SipException {
    if (sipManager == null)
        return;
    if (sipProfile != null) {
        close();
    }
    sipProfile = userProfile.build();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("ru.tenet.sipclient.INCOMING_CALL");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    sipManager.open(sipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
    sipSession = sipManager.createSipSession(sipProfile, new MySipSessionListener());
    sipManager.setRegistrationListener(sipProfile.getUriString(), new MySipRegistrationListener());
}

public void close() {
    try {
        if (sipProfile != null) {
            sipManager.close(sipProfile.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.e("mylog", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}
//getters and setters
```

I tried to remove this

```
sipSession = sipManager.createSipSession(sipProfile, new MySipSessionListener());
```

In this case I will not get any Exception, but *SipRegistrationListener* callbacks will not getting call.

And only reboot helps..

Someone faced this problem? I didn't find any correct solution for this..

**SOLUTION**
The problem is in my device or firmware (Samsung Galaxy s4, Android 5.0.1 official, but some integrated apps were deleted with root).
Checked on Samsung Galaxy s4 with Android 4.3.1 with cyanogen - no problem.

Comment: I think the problem was not on your device. I'm having the same issue on a Moto G and on a LG G2... only reboots seem to solve

Comment: Yes, it realy looks like an android bug.

Answer (score 0):

Create your SipSession before attempting to open the profile for sending or receiving calls.

```
    sipSession = sipManager.createSipSession(sipProfile, new MySipSessionListener());
    sipManager.open(sipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
```

Comment: Getting `android.net.sip.SipException: Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable?` on this `sipSession = sipManager.createSipSession(sipProfile, new MySipSessionListener());`
I'm starting to think that there is bug in android SipManager.
Actually, I don't need SipSession object, and used it to explain the problem;

Comment: Are you sure your sip server is working correctly?  I can produce that error if I put an invalid sip host in there.  Have you tried to capture the sip registration with WireShark or tcpdump?

Comment: Yes, sip is working correctly and I can make calls (checked).
But if my sip connection was interrupted (eg reinstall application), then I can't get callback from `MySipRegistrationListener()`. Just nothing. No REGISTER packets on SIP server... But after device reboot it works, I can see REGISTER packets on server...

Comment: Sounds like you are beyond an application problem.  App re-install should destroy everything at the app level.  Is this reproduceable on multiple devices?  After the restart, can you tell what port it is listening on (netstat -an)  and then check the port availability after force killing the app.

Comment: I tried on other device and... it's ok! The problem is not actual here..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and have not been able to programmatically correct it.  Current solution is to add a delayed handler of 10 seconds to check if the OnRegistrationDone and OnRegistering events have fired during that time.  The following code is placed immediately before the manager.setRegistrationListener method in the initializeLocalProfile function.  When this error condition is detected, the SIP preferences activity is launched and the user notified with SIP Library Error, requesting them to restart the device.  The same handler also detects problems connecting to the defined SIP server with the Server Not Found notification to the user.  Both of these error conditions normally trigger the "registration timed out" error, but you cannot differentiate the two error types in that event, and it takes 30 seconds to time out.

```
            if (!manager.isOpened(me.getUriString())) {
                if (me_listener == null) {
                    manager.open(me, pi, null);
                } else {
                    manager.open(me, pi, me_listener);
                }
            }
            // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
            // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

            if (me_listener == null) {
                bConnecting = true;
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (sentConnecting == false && bLocalOpen == false) { //never connected or connecting
                            updateStatus("SIP Library Error");
                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.remove("namePref");
                            editor.remove("domainPref");
                            editor.putString("statusPref", "SIP Library Error - Please Restart Device and Try Again");
                            editor.commit();
                            updatePreferences();
                            return;
                        } else if (bConnecting == true && bLocalOpen == false) { //never connected
                            updateStatus("Server Not Found");
                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.remove("namePref");
                            editor.remove("domainPref");
                            editor.putString("statusPref", "Server Not Found, Please Edit and Try Again");
                            editor.commit();
                            updatePreferences();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }, 10000);
```