# How can I make call via Sip and SipManager on Delphi FMX Android Platform?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

My SipManager is open and ready with my SipProfile.

```
mysipmanager.open(mysipprofile,mypendingintent,nil);
```

But, While make call, I got this error:

android.net.sip.SipException: Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable?.

My code:

```
mysipaudiocalllistener:=TjSipAudioCall_Listener.Create;
mysipmanager.makeAudioCall(mysipprofile,yoursipprofile,mysipaudiocalllistener,30);
```

How can I make call via Sip and SipManager on Delphi FMX Android Platform?

Thanks,

Best Regards,

Comment: Regarding the error, there are a number of suggestions, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721855/failed-to-create-sipsession-network-unavailable-and-only-reboot-helps. Also, creating an instance of TJSipAudioCall_Listener is not going to do anything: you need to implement a *descendant* of it and override the methods, and that cannot be done in Delphi: you need to do it in Java

Comment: Dear Dave, Hello, Very thanks for your precious and helpful comments. Your comments are very important for me. I'm trying a voice call app (etc. Whatsapp voice call) on Delphi FMX Android Platform. I'm using "android.net.sip" in Android Api and I'm developing app on Delphi FMX Android Platform. So, There did a lot of problems with regard to this app. I started to this app but Unfortunately, I didn't progress on this app. Is this app doable on Delphi FMX Android Platform? What must I do about this app? Thanks, Best Regards.

Comment: Virtually everything can be implemented on Android with Delphi, however as I described, some things cannot be done in Delphi code alone, such as creating a descendant of a Java class - at present, that must be done in Java. Your Delphi app however can use that descendant. I have had a quick look for some simple examples of this, however they seem to be rare. You may gain some insight from reading the FMX source, in particular units that use the Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero unit, and the Java source under the <BDS>\source\rtl\androiddex\java\fmx\src folder

Comment: Dear Dave, Very thanks to you for everything. <BDS>\source\rtl\androiddex\java\fmx\src folder will be very important for me. I will investigate to this folder and releated samples in detail. And I will try to run some android api sip codes via this folder. Best regards.

Comment: Dear Dave, There are some datas in your DW.Androidapi.JNI.LocalBroadcastManager Unit. ['{5CCF81B2-E170-47C4-873E-32E644085880}'] and ['{B5D9B2DA-E150-4CC5-BBDA-58FCD42C6C1E}'] for JObjectClass and JObject. What are these datas? How can I get these datas for other JObjectClasses and Jobjects? Best Regards.

Comment: Those GUIDs are generated automatically when using the Java2OP import tool.

Comment: Ok, Also I will investigate Java2OP import tool with regard to Java and Delphi. Very thanks again. Best Regards.